# The Ultimate Chess Strategy

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story, chess, metapuzzles

I’ve been trying to learn chess so I was googling chess strategies. When I saw an ad for “The Ultimate Chess Strategy,” I instantly followed it and put in my credit card number. A few days later I received a package from Australia. I opened it and found what looks like a children’s place mat from a family restaurant. Have I been had? What is the Ultimate Chess Strategy?
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### A word search

> This is a word search for the six piece names, with the twist that you read along the paths of the pieces; for instance, the queen starts in the lower right Q, then moves to the center U, then right to the E on the border...
>
>  [image: piece movements]
>  Interestingly, the pawn first moves two spaces forwards; then it moves diagonally (capturing another piece)... and then promotes to a knight to reach an N!
>
>  The leftover letters spell **CHANCE**.

### reBus

> As hinted by "elementary" in the flavortext, this is a rebus using chemical elements.
>
>  Element #66 is Dysprosium, `Dy`.
>  Element #99 is Einsteinium, `Es`.
>  Element #50 is Tin, `Sn`.
>
>  If we use the full name for Tin and the abbreviations for the two others, it spells out `[D[Es][Tin]y]`, so the answer to this subpuzzle is **DESTINY**.

### Crossword

> This is a crossword; letters go in the white cells, with the starting and ending positions given for each clue.
>
>  [image: crossword grid]
>
>  The long diagonal doesn't get any clues, and the corner cells don't get checking from entries... but there's only one word it could be: **BLESSING**.

### connect the Dots

> This appears to be a "connecting wall", where the words should be divided up into four groups of four.
>
>  The groups (as found by Stiv in their answer) are:
>
>  **Group 1: One letter away from a *Peanuts* character**
>  PARTY (PA**T**TY), SALTY (SAL**L**Y), SINUS (**L**INUS), SNOOTY (SNOO**P**Y)
>
>  **Group 2: Types of 'stroke'**
>  BUTTERFLY stroke, stroke of GENIUS, (at the) stroke of MIDNIGHT, SIDE stroke
>
>  **Group 3: Initial letter can be changed to make a unit of currency**
>  BOUND (**P**OUND), COLLAR (**D**OLLAR), FROWN (**C**ROWN), PRANK (**F**RANK)
>
>  **Group 4: Animal noise missing first letter**
>  (B)ARK, (O)INK, (R)OAR, (H)OWL
>
>
>  The word LUCK satisfies all four of these categories (LUC**Y**, stroke of luck, **B**UCK, (C)LUCK). So **LUCK** is the answer to this subpuzzle.

### Example

> As hinted by "blindly" and "feel", the chess pieces are arranged in Braille, spelling out **DREAMS**.

### the ultimeta chess strategy

> Index into the puzzle answers using the given coordinates. For instance, `c8` means "take the 8th letter of puzzle C's answer, BLESSING", so the first letter is G.
>
>  Doing this for all the coordinates tells us the "ultimate chess strategy"...  **GUESS AND CHECK, MATE**.

Comment: (Feel free to incorporate the Connecting Wall solution from my answer into yours so we have a complete solution...)

Answer (score 6):

A word search:

> We find the names of chess pieces by moving from letter to letter the same way that corresponding piece would move on a chessboard. Then we just look at the letters that were never stepped on, and they spell out the word **CHANCE**.
>
> [image: 1]

reBus:

> I looked up elements by their atomic number. 66 is Dysprosium [Ds], 99 is Einsteinium [Es], and 50 is Tin. Then [6 [99] [50] 6] spells out [D [Es] [Tin] y], or **DESTINY**.

Crossword:

> Rook's alias: CASTLE
>  Horizontal row: RANK
>  Chess __ Svenska: PA
>  Footmen before horsemen: G PAWNS
>  Capture a piece or win a title: SNAG
>  King's rook in Spanish descriptive notation: TR
>
> Phillips & Drew Kings finale __ Chess Challenge: GLC
>  Estonian bishop in English: SPEAR
>  A pawn may capture a pawn en __: PASSANT
>  Battle between black and red: ANTS WAR?
>  "Pioneer of the modern style of chess" Josef: KLING
>  Letters used to denote Knights: ENS
>
> The solved puzzle is pictured below. I guessed that the answer to this puzzle would be a word that could be read down along the main diagonal from left to right, which would be **BLESSING**.
>
> [image: 2]

connect the Dots:

> SALT(L)Y, S(L)INUS, PAR(T)TY, SNOOT(P)Y: Peanuts characters with one letter changed.
>  GENIUS, BUTTERFLY, MIDNIGHT, SIDE: Strokes
>  O(E)AR, F(B)ROWN, B(H)OUND, P(F)RANK: Words related to "dog" when the first letter is changed?
>
> Wasn't quite sure if this is right, or how to categorize the rest, but I'm guessing the word that unites them all is **LUCKY**.
>
> EDIT: See @Stiv's answer [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/116447/21369) for a correct solution to this Connect Wall puzzle.

Example:

> The pieces on the board form Braille characters which spell out the word **DREAMS**.

Putting it all together:

> **A** word search: CHANCE
>  re**B**us: DESTINY
>  **C**rossword: BLESSING
>  connect the **D**ots: LUCKY
>  **E**xample: DREAMS
>  C8 D2 A6 B3 C4 E4 B6 E1 D3 A2 C3 A5 D4, E5, A3 B4 E3#
>
> Taking the appropriately-numbered letter from the answer to each lettered puzzle gives us GUESSANDCHECK,MATE. So what is the ultimate chess strategy?  **GUESS AND CHECK, MATE**!

Comment: I believe it should just be LUCK, not LUCKY - that would fit the categories better?

Comment: Aha, didn't spot this Connecting Wall attempt when posting my own, but I believe I have it solved :) (And I totally agree with two of your groups...)

Comment: Ah, yes, you're both correct - I sensed I was close to solving the whole puzzle so I kind of rushed my way through the last few parts.  @Stiv your solution for the Connecting Wall is clearly correct.

Comment: Cool puzzle! It would have been much cooler if the last part chess moves are the actual moves to get a check mate, but I guess that's too hard, lol

Answer (score 4):

To fill in the gap in @Deusovi's answer, here's the Connecting Wall solution to 'connect the Dots':

> **Group 1: One letter away from a *Peanuts* character**
>  PARTY (PA**T**TY), SALTY (SAL**L**Y), SINUS (**L**INUS), SNOOTY (SNOO**P**Y)
>
>  **Group 2: Connection with 'stroke'**
>  BUTTERFLY stroke, stroke of GENIUS, (at the) stroke of MIDNIGHT, SIDE stroke
>
>  **Group 3: Initial letter can be changed to make a unit of currency**
>  BOUND (**P**OUND), COLLAR (**D**OLLAR), FROWN (**C**ROWN), PRANK (**F**RANK)
>
>  **Group 4: Animal noise missing first letter**
>  (B)ARK, (O)INK, (R)OAR, (H)OWL

All of which means the missing word required for the metapuzzle is:

> **LUCK**
>  *Peanuts* character: LUC**Y**
>  'Stroke' connection: A stroke of LUCK
>  Unit of currency: **B**UCK
>  Animal noise: (C)LUCK

This provides the necessary letters for the final metapuzzle answer already deduced by Deusovi...